# How to use GroupBy with ICollections?

Tags: c#, linq

I use GroupBy to grouping objects like:

```
var categories=
    tovRDb.MyObjects.AsEnumerable().Where(t => myHashSet.Contains(t.Id))
                      .GroupBy(t => t.Specialization, t => t,
                               (key, g) => new {Name = key.Name, CategoryItems = g.ToList()})
                      .OrderBy(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Name))
                      .ThenBy(t => t.Name)
                      .ToList();
```

It's works fine.
But now i want to group objects where Specialization is ICollection<>.
For example:

```
MyObject1: "Berlay's Meat"
Specializations{Chicken, Pork, Beef}

MyObject2: "Wonday's Chickery"
Specializations{Chicken}


MyObject3: "Rooki's Meat"
Specializations{Chicken, Pork}
```

And after group by:

```
Pork{MyObject1: "Berlay's Meat",MyObject3: "Rooki's Meat"}
Beef{MyObject1: "Berlay's Meat"}
Chicken{MyObject1: "Berlay's Meat",MyObject2: "Wonday's Chickery", MyObject3: "Rooki's Meat"}
```

Any advises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With`categories` as:

```
var categories = tovRDb.MyObjects.AsEnumerable().Where(t => myHashSet.Contains(t.Id));

var catsGrouped = categories.SelectMany(
    x => x.Specializations, // Specializations is an IEnumerable<Specialization>
    (x, y) => new
    {
        Category = x,
        Specialization = y,
    }).GroupBy(x => x.Specialization, x => x.Category)
    .ToArray();
```

I used the `SelectMany` to "multiply" each category for its specializations... Then I regrouped the result by `Specialization`. The result is a `IGrouping<Specialization, MyObject>[]`